# Keras loading model issue

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

So I'm having an issue and I'm stuck on it for a while now

I'm trying to understand and repeat a jupyter tutorial about adversarial example.
However, when I'm loading a model, depending on how is it done I have big differences between the two models accuracy:
  - when it's loading inside a class, there is no issues
  - when it's loading on jupyter, the accuracy decrease

The class use the following lines:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model

class Lenet:

  def __init__(self, epochs=200, batch_size=128, load_weights=True):
    self.name               = 'lenet'
    self.model_filename     = 'networks/models/lenet.h5'
    self.num_classes        = 10
    self.input_shape        = 32, 32, 3
    self.batch_size         = batch_size
    self.epochs             = epochs
    self.iterations         = 391
    self.weight_decay       = 0.0001
    self.log_filepath       = r'networks/models/lenet/'

    if load_weights:
        try:
            self._model = load_model(self.model_filename)
            print('Successfully loaded', self.name)
        except (ImportError, ValueError, OSError):
            print('Failed to load', self.name)
```

what I am doing is:

```
modelPath = "networks/models/lenet.h5"
lenet2 = keras.models.load_model(modelPath)

modelPath2 = "networks/models/resnet.h5"
resnet2 = keras.models.load_model(modelPath2)
```

However, when I'm testing the accuracy of the two models:

```
lenet = LeNet()
resnet = ResNet() #the class is nearly the same as LeNet
models = [lenet, lenet2, resnet, resnet2]
network_stats, correct_imgs = helper.evaluate_models(models, x_test, y_test)
network_stats = pd.DataFrame(network_stats, columns=['name', 'accuracy', 'param_count'])
```

I'm getting this following result: (network_stats)

```
name                accuracy    param_count
0   lenet           0.7488            62006
1   sequential_1    0.4800            62006
2   resnet          0.9231           470218
3   model_1         0.1092           470218
```

[link to the  picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY3H3.jpg)

to explain the picture: on the left, [this is the class lenet](https://github.com/Hyperparticle/one-pixel-attack-keras/blob/master/networks/lenet.py), that give good results. On the right, my failed try to load the same model

Do you have any idea about why is that happening?

--edit--

can't post images yet on stackoverflow, so I explained a little bit more the issue

--edit2--

can reproduce with another network (resnet)

Comment: Perhaps the down-voter could explain why they down voted this question so people can learn how to improve their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the link to the tutorial you are following?

Are you training the model or just testing the accuracy?

My guess... the class has a color preprocessing function that is transforming the input in the "accuracy" method. If the non-class model is not using that same function then that's about the outcome discrepancy I would expect to see.

```
    def accuracy(self):
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
        y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, self.num_classes)
        y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, self.num_classes)

        # color preprocessing
        x_train, x_test = self.color_preprocessing(x_train, x_test)  # <--- here

        return self._model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)[1]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer

yes there is a color preprocessing, but I didn't knew the purpose (I'll check what is this)

After a quick look at it, the class is using color preprocessing for training & prediction, this is why in the evaluate function I didn't see it (the function evaluate only check if the predicted image is correct)